# Python - re.sub redundant piece of code to be replaced a function

Tags: python, regex, function

I have a Python script that needs to replace strings in line using regex (re.sub) and this works exactly as expected.

Therefore, the same piece of code is being called multiple times in my code (because this operation is required in multiple sections), i would like to simplify the code through a simple function.

**Here are the re.sub operations:**

```
# Replace bank char followed by % 
line=re.sub(r'\s\%','_PCT',line)

# Replace % at beginning of a word
line=re.sub(r'(?<=[a-zA-Z0-9\,])%(?=[a-zA-Z0-9]+|$)','PCT',line)

# Replace any other % 
line=re.sub(r'\%','_PCT',line)

# Replace blank space between 2 groups of chars
line=re.sub(r'(?<=[a-zA-Z0-9]) (?=[a-zA-Z0-9]+|$)','_',line)

# Replace +
line=re.sub(r'\+','',line)

# Replace "(" by "_"
line=re.sub(r'\(','_',line)

# Replace ")" by nothing
line=re.sub(r'\)','',line)

# Replace =0 by nothing
line=re.sub(r'\=0','',line)
```

**And the "line" definition which comes from "data" read from stdin:**

```
# Read nmon data from stdin
data = sys.stdin.readlines()

for line in data:

...
```

I have tried to create a simple function with no argument to call it later in my code when required but this won't work as variables are only valid in the function context.

Is there any simple way i could achieve to replace redundant piece of code with a simple function ?

The full code can be seen here if it helps:
http://pastebin.com/D9gb1B4V

Edit: piece of code tried:

Ok thanks to comments, i have tried this with no luck:

```
def subreplace(line):

    # Replace bank char followed by % 
    line=re.sub(r'\s\%','_PCT',line)

    # Replace % at beginning of a word
    line=re.sub(r'(?<=[a-zA-Z0-9\,])%(?=[a-zA-Z0-9]+|$)','PCT',line)

    # Replace any other % 
    line=re.sub(r'\%','_PCT',line)

    # Replace blank space between 2 groups of chars
    line=re.sub(r'(?<=[a-zA-Z0-9]) (?=[a-zA-Z0-9]+|$)','_',line)

    # Replace +
    line=re.sub(r'\+','',line)

    # Replace "(" by "_"
    line=re.sub(r'\(','_',line)

    # Replace ")" by nothing
    line=re.sub(r'\)','',line)

    # Replace =0 by nothing
    line=re.sub(r'\=0','',line)

    return line
```

Then:

```
            # Replace trouble strings
            subreplace(line)
```

Where i normally have the code executed

Comment: Could you show a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code you've tried and e.g. full error traceback in the question itself. It's not clear what you mean by *"variables are only valid in the function context"*. Also, you probably want at least one parameter for your function; the `line`.

Comment: If the order you are changing the lines does not change just make a function that takes the line as an arg and returns the cleaned line.

Comment: Why are you creating a function with no argument? The function should take an argument, which is the `line` variable. It should then perform all the substitutions, and return the updated `line`. Then you would call it as `line = do_all_subs(line)`.

Comment: Hi, Thank you all for your help !

@Barmar: thanks you gave me the answer which helped me to get it :)
I was not calling the function the way i should...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to comments and great help for my very young experience in Python, the answer is:

def subreplace(line):

```
# Replace bank char followed by % 
line=re.sub(r'\s\%','_PCT',line)

# Replace % at beginning of a word
line=re.sub(r'(?<=[a-zA-Z0-9\,])%(?=[a-zA-Z0-9]+|$)','PCT',line)

# Replace any other % 
line=re.sub(r'\%','_PCT',line)

# Replace blank space between 2 groups of chars
line=re.sub(r'(?<=[a-zA-Z0-9]) (?=[a-zA-Z0-9]+|$)','_',line)

# Replace +
line=re.sub(r'\+','',line)

# Replace "(" by "_"
line=re.sub(r'\(','_',line)

# Replace ")" by nothing
line=re.sub(r'\)','',line)

# Replace =0 by nothing
line=re.sub(r'\=0','',line)

return line
```

And to call the function like:

```
                # Replace trouble strings
                line = subreplace(line)
```